# SQL Server 2016 return empty result sometime

Tags: search, full-text-search, sql-server-2016, is-empty

It is a very normal query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE CONTAINS(ProductName,'Samsung')
```

My problem is SQL Server 2016 Express full text search returns an empty result sometimes, and only when I detect it and restart server then it works again.

So far it occurs at least twice. After restarting it seems to work as expected.
I have also check by directly execute the query in SQL Server Management Studio and had the same results. Also, SQL Server FTS seems to run in both case when checking on SQL Server service configuration.

What could cause this issue? Thanks

Comment: Without more details, it's very hard to tell... but I'd suggest reviewing your server settings, perhaps a option you've enabled to improve speed?  Since it's intermittent, It could also be something to do with query caches?

I do know that matches can fail silently in some scenarios.  You might want to review the query output to see if it's throwing a code.

Comment: My hosting support says it could be something relate to sql feature deprecated in Sql 2016, so I edit the query a little bit in case of two or more words to see if the issue occurs again. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName like '%Samsung%'
```

I think this will solve your problem

Comment: No, it is not. My question is about why Full Text Search not run sometime why it is expected to run all the time.